# PHP not inserting to MYSQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu-11.10

I have a html form, a php script and a mysql database I want the form to post to the mysql database through the php script. i fill out the form and submit but the table stays the same. I'm using Lamp setup with Ubuntu.

```
/var/www/add_review.php
<?
$username="user";
$password="password";
$database="database";
$review=$_POST['review'];
$Cname=$_POST['Cname'];
$picture=$_POST['picture'];
$profile=$_POST['Cprofile'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
$ratingImg=$_POST['ratingImg'];
$rating=$_POST['rating'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$Creview=$_POST['Creview'];
$link=$_POST['link'];
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$review','$Cname','$picture','$location','$ratingImg','$rating','$date','$Creview','$link')";
mysql_query($query);
if($query)
{
    echo "Success!";
}
else
{
    die(mysql_error());
}
mysql_close();
echo "Review Added!";
echo "<br />";
echo $review;
echo "<br />";
echo $name;
echo "<br />";
echo $picture;
echo "<br />";
echo $profile;
echo "<br />";
echo $location;
echo "<br />";
echo $ratingImg;
echo "<br />";
echo $rating;
echo "<br />";
echo $date;
echo "<br />";
echo $Creview;
echo "<br />";
echo $link;
?>

/var/www/add_review.html
<h1>Add A Drink</h1>
<form action="add_review.php" method="post">
<p>Review # <input type="text" name="review"><br></p>
<p>UserName <input type="text" name="Cname"><br></p>
<p>Picture URL <input type="text" name = "picture"><br></p>
<p>Users Profile URL <input type="text" name = "Cprofile"><br></p>
<p>Location <input type="text" name = "location"><br></p>
<p>Star URL <input type="text" name = "ratingImg"><br></p>
<p>Star Value <input type="text" name = "rating"><br></p>
<p>Date(MMDDYYYY) <input type="text" name = "date"><br></p>
<p>Users Review<br> <textarea name="Creview"></textarea><br></p>
<p>Review Link <input type="text" name = "link"><br></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

MYSQL Table

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| review    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Cname     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| picture   | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Cprofile  | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| location  | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ratingImg | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rating    | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Creview   | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| link      | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong! please help.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Truth, totally going to steal your comment for future use!

Comment: well i had no idea, i just learned MYSQL 8 months ago... you know you slacking when your "go-to" solution is now being phased out and becoming "obsolete" lol well i will catch up on mysqli but in the mean time have any idea what up with this?

Comment: it's a bad idea to name columns with reserved words like `date`

Comment: @JohnConde: All credit goes to teresko at PHP chat. You're welcome to join :)

Comment: no errors, but the table is bone dry.

Comment: i finally made the inserted the fields but it looks like this

Comment: well its too long but it doesn't look like  right

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be supplying a value for `CProfile` which will probably cause an error of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

In your INSERT sentence, the int values does not require quotes.

From now on, please supply error messages (if you don't see one, look for it on apache error log)

Answer (score 1):

try specifying your columns in your query:

```
$query = <<<EOQ

INSERT INTO yelpreviews(review, Cname, picture, location, 
                        ratingImg, rating, `date`, Creview, link)
VALUES('$review','$Cname','$picture','$location',
       '$ratingImg','$rating','$date','$Creview','$link')

EOQ;
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean `$_POST['image']`? Is that you're uploading image? If so, i'm sure you use the enctype = multipart/form-data on the form attribute, and also you use $_FILE['image']['name'] to get the name of the image.

One more thing, you should use the `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['string'])` to prevent mysql injection. And also do not use quote between integer values.

Comment: as far as the $_POST['image'] I'm just entering a url of the image.